# How to create a "configure" file?

Tags: linux, apache, mapserver

Recently I downloaded a file using the following link

```
git clone git://github.com/mapserver/mapcache.git
```

Inside the downloaded mapcache folder I can not find a configure file to do "./configure". But the installation help file tell:

> ### Unix compilation instructions
>
> If you are using a git clone rather than a tarball distribution, you
>   must first run autoconf in the root directory, to create the configure
>   file from configure.in:
>
> $ autoconf
>
> For unix users, the compilation process should resume to:
>
> $ ./configure
>
> $ make
>
> (as root)
>
> ## make install-module
>
> The installation script takes care of putting the built module in the
>   apache module directory.

To do `./configure` there should be a configure file isn't it? Please show me how to make one to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Did you run `autoconf` as explained in the instructions?

Comment: @Matteo yes. But I get "autoconf: error: no input file" I do not no what input file it asks.

Comment: then you should update your question. In any case the file is not there and the documentation is not in sync with the content of the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maintainer speaking ...

mapcache and mapserver are switching to cmake for the next release and the docs for the master branch need updating. You can either use the branch-1-0 branch to continue using autoconf builds, or use cmake with master:

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Answer (score 2):

The help file tells you exactly what you need to do

> If you are using a git clone rather than a tarball distribution, you must first run autoconf in the root directory, to create the configure file from configure.in

If you don't already have `autoconf` installed you'll need to install it in the normal way for your distribution.

Comment: Yes I have autoconf installed but when I run it I get an error indicating to specify a input file: "autoconf: error: no input file"

Comment: What is this root directory mean? Is it the downloaded mapcache folder itself or another?

Answer (score 0):

The repository seems out of sync with the documentation

- there is no `configure.in` as mentioned in the `INSTALL` file (nowhere not only in the root directory)
- there is just a `Makefile.vc` file for MSVC++

You should contact the maintainer